# Define by default columnDefs

Tags: ag-grid

I want to use by default all the datas from rowData, I do not want use specific values. Do you know how to unify columnDefs for both examples?

1st example:

```
columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'make', field: 'make' },
    {headerName: 'model', field: 'model' },
    {headerName: 'price', field: 'price'}
];

rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
];
```

2nd example:

```
columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'name', field: 'name' },
    {headerName: 'phone', field: 'phone' },
];

rowData = [
    { name: 'Manuel', phone: 35000 },
    { name: 'Maria', phone: 32000 },
    { name: 'John', phone: 72000 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one idea, but dont exactly know if it is more elegant.

```
var columnDefs = [
  { headerName: "make", field: "make" },
  { headerName: "model", field: "model" },
  { headerName: "price", field: "price" }
];

var rowData = [
  { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
  { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
  { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
];

 genColums() {
  let columsDef = [];
  for (var prop in rowData[0]) {
    columsDef.push({
      headerName: prop,
      field: prop
    });
  }
  console.log(columsDef);
}

this.genColums();
```

**PS.** this work, if all data same, in each object

Comment: If need some help - be free to ask me!